# How to averages models using scikitlearn Cross Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I've always read that Cross Validation can be used to **create multiple splits, then average the model** to avoid overfitting, but have not been able to find an example doing that.

Looking at `scikitlearn`, I only see examples of `cross_val_score` that gives you the CV score across multiple splits for you to **evaluate whether there is overfitting** such as [here](https://stackabuse.com/cross-validation-and-grid-search-for-model-selection-in-python/)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
all_accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=classifier, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=5)
```

How can one uses CV to actually **average the models** across the splits ?

Comment: cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/477489/232706

Comment: What you report to have always read is just wrong: CV does **not** average models (which I guess makes your question at the end of your post actually invalid), neither it is used to "prevent" or "avoid" overfitting.

Comment: In that case, how does GridSearchCV give you **one** single model for **one** set of hyper-param, when you specify CV = x > 2 and the report actually said it fits x times ? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

Comment: It doesn't, it's job is to give you the optimal values of the hyperparameters that you can then use to fit a single model.

Comment: In the general case of k folds and M hyperparameter combinations (i.e. different models actually), it first finds the best combination (model), and then refits that model with the whole dataset (check the `refit` argument in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html); default value is `True`). In the special case you refer to, it just reports the score of the single model tried (this is a valid use of CV in itself, w/o any grid search actually), and then it again refits it with the whole of the data.

Comment: Interesting. I might have misunderstood. But then, consider you have **only 1** set of hyperparams and specify CV=5 with GridSearchCV. It splits 5 times, fits 5 models with **the same hyperparam**. Which model/estimator is then reported ? Because in the end, I am only seeing 1 model I can use to predict test set.

Comment: Looking closely, you'll see that you have actually answered the question yourself: the terms "model" and "hyperparameter combination" are actually **synonyms** - an (unfitted) model is a particular combination of hyperparameters, nothing else. So, it just reports the results of this single model (after fitting it k times and averaging the scores), and then [refer to my comment above] it fits again with the given hyperparams using the whole dataset.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I was **very** confused myself with this point ~ 10 years ago, when I started learning about ML (... *but what is the exact final model...?* ) ;)

Comment: I do agree on **unfitted model = hyperparam combination**; I just tend to use **model** as the post-fitted result, when all the coefficients are known and ready to be saved or applied on test set. On GridSearchCV, if there are multiple hyperparam sets and CV=x, is the following statement correct : **for each hyperparam set**, fits x models, get x scores, average those score into 1 single score. Then, compare this score with those from other hyperparam sets. When the winner is found, use this set to refit all training data. This refit only does once for the winner and not at each hyperparam set

Comment: This is the exact procedure indeed ;)

Comment: And I always appreciate the altruistic sharing such as you have done. Hats off with respect. Knowledge is to be shared and passed forward :)

Comment: I do have another question here on how to pick out individual models from GridSearchCV and apply customized scoring method to find the winner. Just threw in my thought process, and some of them may not be reasonable. Would be great if you could share your thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864193/get-individual-models-and-customized-score-in-gridsearchcv-and-randomizedsearchc/62938603#62938603